# PostgreSQL `at timezone` unexpected behaviour

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, timezone, timestamp-with-timezone

When running the following queries, the expected result would be the same (2023-01-16 16:39:24.824000) as the current timezone in `Europe/Tirana` is CEST. However, the results I receive are as shown:

```
select '2023-01-16 14:39:24.824000 +00:00' at time zone 'Europe/Tirane';
select '2023-01-16 14:39:24.824000 +00:00' at time zone 'CEST';
```

```
2023-01-16 15:39:24.824000
2023-01-16 16:39:24.824000
```

Meaning that `Europe/Tirana` does not return the correct result. Am I missing something? Why is this behaviour happening? Thank you in advance!

I tried using ::timestamptz and some other suggestions I found but the result remained unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is correct because the `Europe/Tirane` time zone was switched from `CET` (UTC+1) to `CEST` (UTC+2) on 2023-03-26.

```
2023    dim 26 mar, 02 h 00 CET → CEST  +1 hour (DST start) UTC+2h
        dim 29 oct, 03 h 00 CEST → CET  -1 hour (DST end)   UTC+1h
```

so the result of : `select '2023-01-16 14:39:24.824000 +00:00' at time zone 'Europe/Tirane';`

should be `2023-01-16 15:39:24.824` , because `2023-01-16` is before `2023-03-26`

Comment: Totally overlooked that, thank you!